# Can't Import BertTokenizer

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am attempting to use the BertTokenizer part of the transformers package. First I install as below.

```
pip install transformers
```

Which says it succeeds.

When I try to import parts of the package as below I get the following.

```
 from transformers import BertTokenizer
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-89505a24ece6>", line 1, in <module>
    from transformers import BertTokenizer

  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .integrations import (  # isort:skip

  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\integrations.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .trainer_utils import PREFIX_CHECKPOINT_DIR, BestRun  # isort:skip

  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer_utils.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .tokenization_utils_base import ExplicitEnum

  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tokenizers import AddedToken

  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tokenizers\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .tokenizers import Tokenizer, Encoding, AddedToken

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tokenizers.tokenizers'
```

The package is detailed here so I think it should be available
https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html

Answer (score 5):

You could do that:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
```

it should work correctly.

Anyway I did a test and doing what you did, but it works for me. I can't reproduce your error. Probably you didn't correctly install the library. Try creating a new environment and installing from scratch.

Comment: I'm confused how I could have installed incorrectly, I've pip uninstalled and installed multiple times. What are you suggesting I did wrong? Would you be able to elaborate on making a new environment?

Comment: I created a virtual env with ```anaconda``` and then with pip I installed ```transformers```. By doing this, your code works. You could try to uninstall ```transformers``` (not pip) with pip and install in a new virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The problem seems to be the way I import the tensor flow library. I changed it from `import tensorflow as tf` to `import tensorflow`.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. My system is Win10.

First, I  `pip install transformers==4.10.0,tokenizers==0.10.3`, then it can't work.

```py
from transformers import AlbertConfig, AlbertForPreTraining, load_tf_weights_in_albert
```

```py
File "D:\python-venv\pytorch-venv\lib\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py", line 74, in <module>
    from tokenizers import AddedToken
  File "D:\python-venv\pytorch-venv\lib\site-packages\tokenizers\__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
    from .tokenizers import (
ImportError: DLL load failed:
```

Then, I pip install `transformers==2.11.0,tokenizers==0.7.0`, it work. You can try this.